# Play Youtube videos on windows phone 8.1

Tags: youtube, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

How to play Youtube videos on player in Windows Phone 8.1 App Development?

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found so far is by using the MyToolkit library from codeplex, it is also available as a nuget package!

The documentation on how to use the specific youtube code can be found here http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube

Comment: Great to hear! Maybe you can 'accept' the response as a valid answer too? :)